# xcode Creating 2 UITableViews with same content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create another UITableView with the same values of the other UITableView.
Here is what I have so far.

The first UITableView works just fine, it displays the data as I want. The other one however, does not display anything at all. Just empty cells. The cell2 is supposed to be for the other table.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]]];

    tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Location 1", @"Location 2", @"Location 3", @"Location 4", @"Location 5", @"Location 6", @"Location 7", @"Location 8", @"Location 9", @"Location 10", @"Location 11", @"Location 12", @"Location 13", @"Location 14", nil];

    mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = nil;
    UITableViewCell * cell2 = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Listaus"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    }

    if (cell2 == nil) {
        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Listaus"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [mainDelegate.distances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell2.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

How to fix this and what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the "init" code of your two tableViews ?

Comment: Assuming both `UITableView` delegates (`delegate` and `datasource`) are set to the same view controller, you need to determine which table view is asking for the cell, create the cell for that table, and return that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *initiate && return the cell according to your `tableView`* .

**This should work :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = nil;
    if(tableView == tableView1){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        }

    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Listaus"];
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Listaus"];
        }
    }
     cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [mainDelegate.distances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Let me know, If you have any issues with it.

Comment: Where should I declare the tableView 1?

Comment: That you should decide . Anyhow, you have tableViews right. tableView1 indicates the tableView Name which you have declared (IBOutlet OR Programmatically).